# Material reflection goes weird and black from certain angle

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, node-editor, color

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

I dont want the material of the floor to turn black and weird at certain angles- does anyone know how to fix this and just have the material how shown below
Also having issues whenever I look through the camera- for some reason the world settings etc change as soon as I look through the camera? The angle looks different and the stars are not visible like before.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess the angle counts because you've used the Noise as a Bump. Also, what are you calling weird? The Noise colors are weird if you use them raw, but if you plug a ColorRamp between the Noise and the Principled you'll be able to choose some non-weird colors, no?

Comment: I mean the black shadow in the horizon. And whenever I look through the camera it cuts the view by half as shown in the last two images

Comment: it cuts the view: maybe select your camera, go in the Properties panel > Data > Lens and change the Clipping values?

Comment: Sorry I am a beginner- I can't seem to find that in the properties panel when pressing n, or in the camera tab- am i looking in the wrong place?

Comment: no, I mean the main Properties panel, not the 3D view properties panel, Properties panel is where you find the Render tab / Render Layers / Scene / etc, on the right by default. If you select the camera you'll have a Data tab with a camera icon

Comment: I have added a screenshot- cant find it anywhere sorry for being so useless

Comment: Change the Clipping-> End distance for the camera. Make it a larger value.